# python panda apply compare to external list and remove part of list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a parking lot with cars of different models (nr) and the cars are so closely packed that in order for one to get out one might need to move some others. A little like a 15Puzzle, only I can take one or more cars out of the parking lot. Ordered_car_List includes the cars that will be picked up today, and they need to be taken out of the parking lot with as few non-ordered cars as possible moved. There are more columns to this panda, but this is what I can't figure out.
I have a Program that works good for small sets of data, but it seems that this is not the way of the PANDAS :-)

I have this:

```
cars = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                    'y': [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4],
                   'order_number':[6,6,7,6,7,9,9,10,12]})
cars['order_number_no_dublicates_down'] = None
Ordered_car_List = [6,9,9,10,28]

i=0
while i < len(cars):
    temp_val = cars.at[i, 'order_number']
    if temp_val in Ordered_car_List:
        cars.at[i, 'order_number_no_dublicates_down']  = temp_val
        Ordered_car_List.remove(temp_val)
    i+=1
```

If I use cars.apply(lambda..., how can I change the Ordered_car_List in each iteration?
Is there another approach that I can take?

I found this page, and it made me want to be faster. The Lambda approach is in the middle when it comes to speed, but it still is so much faster than what I am doing now.
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06

[image]

Comment: Why do you want it to have a side effect on the other list?

Comment: I want to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Updating `cars`

We can vectorize this based on two counters:

1. [**`cumcount()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to cumulatively count each unique value in `cars['order_number']`
2. [**`collections.Counter()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count each unique value in `Ordered_car_List`

```py
cumcount = cars.groupby('order_number').cumcount().add(1)
maxcount = cars['order_number'].map(Counter(Ordered_car_List))

#    order_number  cumcount  maxcount
# 0             6         1         1
# 1             6         2         1
# 2             7         1         0
# 3             6         3         1
# 4             7         2         0
# 5             9         1         2
# 6             9         2         2
# 7            10         1         1
# 8            12         1         0
```

So then we only want to keep `cars['order_number']` where `cumcount <= maxcount`:

- either use [**`DataFrame.loc[]`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

  ```py
  cars.loc[cumcount <= maxcount, 'nodup'] = cars['order_number']
  ```
- or [**`Series.where()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)

  ```py
  cars['nodup'] = cars['order_number'].where(cumcount <= maxcount)
  ```
- or [**`Series.mask()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with the condition inverted

  ```py
  cars['nodup'] = cars['order_number'].mask(cumcount > maxcount)
  ```

#### Updating `Ordered_car_List`

The final `Ordered_car_List` is a `Counter()` difference:

```py
Used_car_List = cars.loc[cumcount <= maxcount, 'order_number']

# [6, 9, 9, 10]
```

```py
Ordered_car_List = list(Counter(Ordered_car_List) - Counter(Used_car_List))

# [28]
```

#### Final output

```py
cumcount = cars.groupby('order_number').cumcount().add(1)
maxcount = cars['order_number'].map(Counter(Ordered_car_List))
cars['nodup'] = cars['order_number'].where(cumcount <= maxcount)

#    x  y  order_number  nodup
# 0  1  1             6    6.0
# 1  1  2             6    NaN
# 2  1  3             7    NaN
# 3  1  4             6    NaN
# 4  1  5             7    NaN
# 5  2  1             9    9.0
# 6  2  2             9    9.0
# 7  2  3            10   10.0
# 8  2  4            12    NaN
```

```py
Used_car_List = cars.loc[cumcount <= maxcount, 'order_number']
Ordered_car_List = list(Counter(Ordered_car_List) - Counter(Used_car_List))

# [28]
```

#### Timings

Note that your loop is still very fast with small data, but the vectorized counter approach just scales much better:

[image: timings for loop vs Series.where vs Series.mask vs df.loc]